# I really know nothing about coding and i need someone to help me analyze this crash report to see why my app is crashing

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I know thread 0 is crashing so i only posted that part of the log but i can't figure out why it is crashing, aka the problem

> {"blame":[],"app_name":"Pixel_Car_Racer","timestamp":"2018-04-22 11:42:50.37 -0600","app_version":"1.1.8","slice_uuid":"70c2dc33-214b-3083-bbb0-0a43e47335f6","adam_id":1068808996,"build_version":"1.1.8","bundleID":"studiofurukawa.pixelcarracer","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.1.2 (15B202)","incident_id":"99D6A19C-5F16-455C-9C20-CCE89A68074E","name":"Pixel_Car_Racer","symbolicated":true}
>   Incident Identifier: 99D6A19C-5F16-455C-9C20-CCE89A68074E
>   CrashReporter Key:   343426bf683017a197e33ac41bdc21649de97016
>   Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
>   Process:             Pixel_Car_Racer [1280]
>   Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7D9400EE-9B55-498D-9E45-1D5710524136/Pixel_Car_Racer.app/Pixel_Car_Racer
>   Identifier:          studiofurukawa.pixelcarracer
>   Version:             1.1.8 (1.1.8)
>   Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
>   Role:                Foreground
>   Parent Process:      launchd [1]
>   Coalition:           studiofurukawa.pixelcarracer [535]

Date/Time:           2018-04-22 11:42:49.4013 -0600
Launch Time:         2018-04-22 11:42:44.7561 -0600
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.1.2 (15B202)
Baseband Version:    4.00.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000d4d37beb8
VM Region Info: 0xd4d37beb8 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 49077010105
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO (reserved) 00000001d8000000-00000001e0000000 [128.0M] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
--->
      UNUSED SPACE AT END

Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0       libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1821bc430 0x1821a0000 + 0x1c430       // objc_msgSend + 0x10
1       CoreFoundation                  0x182f98ce8 0x182e18000 + 0x180ce8      // mdict_rehashd + 0xb4
2       CoreFoundation                  0x182e27da0 0x182e18000 + 0xfda0        // -[**NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 0x2d8
3       WebKitLegacy                    0x18c009e34 0x18bff5000 + 0x14e34       // +[WebFrameView(WebInternal) _viewTypesAllowImageTypeOmission:] + 0x184
4       WebKitLegacy                    0x18c009a88 0x18bff5000 + 0x14a88       // +[WebView(WebPrivate) _viewClass:andRepresentationClass:forMIMEType:allowingPlugins:] + 0x5c
5       WebKitLegacy                    0x18c099800 0x18bff5000 + 0xa4800       // -[WebDefaultPolicyDelegate webView:decidePolicyForMIMEType:request:frame:decisionListener:] + 0xbc
6       CoreFoundation                  0x182f61670 0x182e18000 + 0x149670      // __invoking_** + 0x90
7       CoreFoundation                  0x182e406cc 0x182e18000 + 0x286cc       // -[NSInvocation invoke] + 0x124
8       CoreFoundation                  0x182e4516c 0x182e18000 + 0x2d16c       // -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 0x3c
9       WebKitLegacy                    0x18bff9858 0x18bff5000 + 0x4858        // -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 0x9c
10      CoreFoundation                  0x182f5f3bc 0x182e18000 + 0x1473bc      // ***forwarding*** + 0x270
11      CoreFoundation                  0x182e4501c 0x182e18000 + 0x2d01c       // _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 0x5c
12      CoreFoundation                  0x182f61670 0x182e18000 + 0x149670      // **invoking_** + 0x90
13      CoreFoundation                  0x182e406cc 0x182e18000 + 0x286cc       // -[NSInvocation invoke] + 0x124
14      WebCore                         0x18acbb4f4 0x18ac52000 + 0x694f4       // HandleDelegateSource(void*) + 0x6c
15      CoreFoundation                  0x182f022e8 0x182e18000 + 0xea2e8       // **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 0x18
16      CoreFoundation                  0x182f02268 0x182e18000 + 0xea268       // __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 0x58
17      CoreFoundation                  0x182f01b44 0x182e18000 + 0xe9b44       // __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 0x120
18      CoreFoundation                  0x182eff6c8 0x182e18000 + 0xe76c8       // __CFRunLoopRun + 0x418
19      CoreFoundation                  0x182e1ffb8 0x182e18000 + 0x7fb8        // CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 0x1b4
20      GraphicsServices                0x184cb7f84 0x184cad000 + 0xaf84        // GSEventRunModal + 0x64
21      UIKit                           0x18c3f42e8 0x18c381000 + 0x732e8       // UIApplicationMain + 0xd0
22      Pixel_Car_Racer (*)             0x101440fd0 0x100c74000 + 0x7ccfd0
23      libdyld.dylib                   0x18294256c 0x182941000 + 0x156c        // start + 0x4<

Comment: I also cant get xcode because i have a windows computer

Comment: No, you will need MacOS to debug this

Answer (score 4):

The reason is:

> Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>
> Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000d4d37beb8
>
> VM Region Info: 0xd4d37beb8 is not in any region. Bytes after previous region: 49077010105
>
> REGION TYPE START - END [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD REGION DETAIL MALLOC_NANO (reserved) 00000001d8000000-00000001e0000000 [128.0M] rw-/rwx SM=NUL ...(unallocated) --->
>
> UNUSED SPACE AT END

Your app has attempted to read data from a region of memory that it doesn't have access to. The exact function that's doing this reading is `objc_msgSend()`, which is just a method call on some Objective-C object. The code making *that* call is `-[NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]`.

If you look at the stack trace, you'll see that `CFRunLoop` is servicing one of its sources and calling a `WebViewDelegate` for some task. We can't tell from what you've posted what data was going to be inserted into the dictionary.

Here's the stack trace in a readable form:

```
Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 
Thread 0 Crashed: 
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x1821bc430 0x1821a0000 + 0x1c430 // objc_msgSend + 0x10 
1 CoreFoundation 0x182f98ce8 0x182e18000 + 0x180ce8 // mdict_rehashd + 0xb4 
2 CoreFoundation 0x182e27da0 0x182e18000 + 0xfda0 // -[NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 0x2d8 
3 WebKitLegacy 0x18c009e34 0x18bff5000 + 0x14e34 // +[WebFrameView(WebInternal) _viewTypesAllowImageTypeOmission:] + 0x184 
4 WebKitLegacy 0x18c009a88 0x18bff5000 + 0x14a88 // +[WebView(WebPrivate) _viewClass:andRepresentationClass:forMIMEType:allowingPlugins:] + 0x5c 
5 WebKitLegacy 0x18c099800 0x18bff5000 + 0xa4800 // -[WebDefaultPolicyDelegate webView:decidePolicyForMIMEType:request:frame:decisionListener:] + 0xbc 
6 CoreFoundation 0x182f61670 0x182e18000 + 0x149670 // __invoking_ + 0x90 
7 CoreFoundation 0x182e406cc 0x182e18000 + 0x286cc // -[NSInvocation invoke] + 0x124 
8 CoreFoundation 0x182e4516c 0x182e18000 + 0x2d16c // -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 0x3c 
9 WebKitLegacy 0x18bff9858 0x18bff5000 + 0x4858 // -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 0x9c 
10 CoreFoundation 0x182f5f3bc 0x182e18000 + 0x1473bc // forwarding + 0x270 
11 CoreFoundation 0x182e4501c 0x182e18000 + 0x2d01c // _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 0x5c 
12 CoreFoundation 0x182f61670 0x182e18000 + 0x149670 // invoking_ + 0x90 
13 CoreFoundation 0x182e406cc 0x182e18000 + 0x286cc // -[NSInvocation invoke] + 0x124 
14 WebCore 0x18acbb4f4 0x18ac52000 + 0x694f4 // HandleDelegateSource(void*) + 0x6c 
15 CoreFoundation 0x182f022e8 0x182e18000 + 0xea2e8 // CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 0x18 
16 CoreFoundation 0x182f02268 0x182e18000 + 0xea268 // __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 0x58 
17 CoreFoundation 0x182f01b44 0x182e18000 + 0xe9b44 // __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 0x120 
18 CoreFoundation 0x182eff6c8 0x182e18000 + 0xe76c8 // __CFRunLoopRun + 0x418 
19 CoreFoundation 0x182e1ffb8 0x182e18000 + 0x7fb8 // CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 0x1b4 
20 GraphicsServices 0x184cb7f84 0x184cad000 + 0xaf84 // GSEventRunModal + 0x64 
21 UIKit 0x18c3f42e8 0x18c381000 + 0x732e8 // UIApplicationMain + 0xd0 
22 Pixel_Car_Racer (*) 0x101440fd0 0x100c74000 + 0x7ccfd0 
23 libdyld.dylib 0x18294256c 0x182941000 + 0x156c // start + 0x4<
```

As you can see, none of your application's code is running. Instead what appears to have happened is that you either sent a bad pointer to some function or method which intended to use the thing being pointed to later, or you sent what was at the time a valid object pointer, but the object was `autorelease`d or otherwise over-`release`d, and when the `WebViewDelegate` went to insert it into the dictionary, it was already invalid. You might be able to figure out what's going wrong by running with Zombies on.

Comment: Is there an alternative to xcode for window that i can run zombies on

Comment: You can use Zombies from the command-line `instruments` tool.